# How to hide HTTP Header Manager for a image upload post API in jmeter

Tags: api, rest, testing, jmeter

I create two HTTP request, both post REST API. One of the API content-type is "application/json" for which I have added HTTP Header manager. My other API is for to upload the image. While running both APIs I am getting error as "400 Bad request". If I hide "Http header request" image upload API works but my another API which has json code that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Header Manager obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so it's applied to all [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in its scope

- If you have HTTP Header Manager at the same level as HTTP Request samplers - it will be applied to **all of them**
- If you put HTTP Header Manager to be a child of the HTTP Request sampler - it will be applied to **this sampler only**

like this:

[image]